# Aws lex Confirmation prompt limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

Limit of the confirmation prompts in Amazon Lex is upto 5. It should be less than or equal to 5.
Is there any way that we can increase the limit?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about **Clarification prompts** in error handling of Amazon Lex, the answer is **NO**.
At the moment it is not possible. You must give upto 5 Clarification prompts. If you try to give a number more than 5 it will show error.

[image]